# JFrame won't load after placing a function in the constructor

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jbutton

This is the function I'm trying to load:

```
public void ShowButtonsArray()
{
        SeatsUI Form = new SeatsUI();
            Form.setVisible(true);
            Form.setSize(1000, 1000); //Sets the screen's size
            JButton [][] buttonArr = new JButton[15][12];
            int CellSize = 60;

            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < 12; j++)
                {
                    buttonArr[i][j] = new javax.swing.JButton();
                    buttonArr[i][j].setText("" + i + "," + j );
                    buttonArr[i][j].setBounds(j*CellSize, i*CellSize + 50, CellSize, CellSize);
                    buttonArr[i][j].addActionListener(new Java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
                    {
                            //Seat Button Event
                            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
                            {
                                JButton but = (JButton)evt.getSource();
                                but.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                            }
                    }
                    );

                    Form.add(buttonArr[i][j]);
                }
            }
}
```

Before turning this into a function, I wrote it in run() where it worked fine, but after moving it here:

```
public SeatsUI() {
    initComponents();
    ShowButtonsArray();
}
```

It just stopped working. I run the project but it gets stuck for some reason and loads the project forever. What did I do wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: And please : method names NEVER start with a upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call ShowButtonsArray(), you then call SeatsUI Form = new SeatsUI() from within this method and when you call new SeatsUI(), you call ShowButtonsArray() in the constructor. It can't get out of that loop I think.